# how to do a predictive search without using autocomplete function of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I need to create a predictive search just like in google. I accomplished this using jQuery.autocomplete(). But the problem is the website website only support jquery UI 1.8.4. (this version of jQuery doesn't come with autocomplete) and the search didn't work. Also when i pass UI 1.10.3, other functionalities in the website broke.
How can i create something like autocomplete using jQuery UI 1.8.4?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add you reference of a new version of jQuery? That will override the old version and `autocomplete` will work.

```
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
   // your code
</script>
```

Comment: I cannot override the UI, if i did other functionality will not work.

Comment: are you sure? have you tried it?

Comment: Seriously @Ted? The OP: "Also when i pass UI 1.10.3, other functionalities in the website broke."

Answer (score 0):

You can just attach a keyup event to the input field and handle the data request yourself. And add a 500ms timeout before you fire the request, so you don't flood the server and the user with results ...

Answer (score 0):

What you need :

- a `div` tag relatively positioned below the input which must be populated on server call complete (or a `ul` tag as well, any container)
- a `keyup` event on the textbox which passes this as input to the server.

This is merely scratching the surface. Auto complete of jquery UI has been under development for many years and trying to mimic them is only waste of time at this point.

my advice : don't go through with this. You could do any one of these

- Change the version of jquery and be done with it.
- use another autocomplete plugin which isn't dependant on jquery UI. But you might find that they're dependant on jquery. There are tons of plugins. A simple google search is enough to get you started

Comment: I can ask them to upgrade their UI, but possibility is very less. I am not sure whether I will be able to add plugins or not coz I am working on CMS. I will try to add plugins. do you know which plugin is best and easy to use?

Comment: I sometimes use this : http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/.. neat and simple docs